# Cucumber testng runner fails

Tags: java, cucumber, testng

Below is my runner class,

```
package runner;



import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;

//@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="resources/features",glue="step_def")

public class Runner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
 /* private TestNGCucumberRunner testNGCucumberRunner;

    @org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setUpClass() throws Exception {
        testNGCucumberRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());
    }

    @org.testng.annotations.Test(groups = "cucumber", description = "Runs Cucumber Feature", dataProvider = "features")
    public void feature(CucumberFeatureWrapper cucumberFeature) {
        testNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(cucumberFeature.getCucumberFeature());
    }

    @org.testng.annotations.DataProvider
    public Object[][] features() {
        return testNGCucumberRunner.provideFeatures();
    }

    @org.testng.annotations.AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void tearDownClass() throws Exception {
        testNGCucumberRunner.finish();
    }*/
}
```

Whenever I try to run this as a TestNG test, I'm getting the below error

> [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.13.1 [Utils] [ERROR] [Error]
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.features(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:29)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:74)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodNoCheckedException(MethodInvocationHelper.java:45)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:131)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:706)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.ParameterHandler.handleParameters(ParameterHandler.java:49)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.ParameterHandler.createParameters(ParameterHandler.java:37)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:914)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1187)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1116)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1028)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:996)    at
>   org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
>
> FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass setUpClass
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.reporter(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Lgherkin/formatter/Reporter;
>     at
>   cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:41)
>     at
>   cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.setUpClass(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:16)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:451)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:163)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:105)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1187)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1116)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1028)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:996)    at
>   org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
>
> FAILED CONFIGURATION: @AfterClass tearDownClass
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.tearDownClass(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:34)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:451)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeAfterClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:208)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1187)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1116)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1028)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:996)    at
>   org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
>
> SKIPPED: feature
>            Runs Cucumber Feature java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodNoCheckedException(MethodInvocationHelper.java:49)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:131)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:706)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.ParameterHandler.handleParameters(ParameterHandler.java:49)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.ParameterHandler.createParameters(ParameterHandler.java:37)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:914)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1187)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1116)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1028)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:996)    at
>   org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77) Caused
>   by: java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.features(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:29)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:74)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodNoCheckedException(MethodInvocationHelper.java:45)
>     ... 22 more
>
> ===============================================
>       Default test
>       Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
>
> ## Configuration Failures: 2, Skips: 0
>
> =============================================== Default suite Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1 Configuration Failures: 2, Skips:
>
> ## 0

I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: According to your snippet, you have commented out the whole class file, and possibly did not push the new classfile to wherever the `RemoveTestNG` environment is.

Comment: Check the value used in the 'features' option in cucumberoptions. No feature files are found hence the NPE.

Answer (score 1):

The path of the feature file should start with source folder. Try this once.
It should look like :-

features = "src\\bbd_feature"